# CSS line-height smaller than font-size results in odd overflow within a div

Tags: css

I've encountered some bizarre CSS behavior.  However, it works exactly the same across Firefox, Chrome and IE (9) so I suspect it is a part of the CSS standard, however, I cannot find any reference to why it might be the case.

I have a div with some text in it.  When I set the font-size larger than the line height, the height of the div is calculated using the line-height, but the content is much larger.  That is, the text in the box is much larger than the box itself.  I have a jsfiddle with the situation here:

http://jsfiddle.net/RVgzV/4/

If you move the mouse to above the bounding box, you can see the hover css activates before you enter the div.  Similarly, clicking close to, but still outside of the box activates the javascript click event.  It's slightly easier to see where the content box is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/RVgzV/5/

The height is correctly calculated when the display property on the div is set to inline (which I can't do for various styling reasons).  Also, the issue is solved if I set the overflow property to hidden.  To me this indicates that the content is larger than its containing box, but I am not sure why.  In particular I want to know why the "height" css box model property of the object is smaller than its actual height as displayed on the page.

I've had a look through the CSS spec, and I didn't see my answer there, but I suspect there may be something there I am missing.

**Edit**

I've found the following link which makes some reference to the problem I am having, but I have no idea what their source is, or why it might be the case.

Also, in response to some answers I have received, I am not looking for how to fix my css so the hover issue doesn't appear anymore, I am looking for **why** it's happening in the first place.

**Edit Again**
Apparently, any content of the box, no matter whether inside the box's boundaries or not invokes hover on the box.  (See Mr. Lister's comment on [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093218/css-line-height-smaller-than-font-size-results-in-an-incorrectly-sized-div#10093816).  What I'd really like to know is where in the specification this behavior comes from.  Is it in there?  Or is it an implementation that all browsers have agreed on?

Comment: Since you can make a div larger by increasing the line-height of the text inside of it, it's only natural that you can also make the div smaller by decreasing the line-height. To me the only surprise here is that the hovering area has become non-rectangular.

Comment: Yes, and that is what I am surprised about as well. I was _hoping_ to make the box smaller using line-height, what I didn't want is the hover behavior (which as I have mentioned, can be solved by using overflow:hidden)

Answer (score 1):

Use overflow:hidden to hide anything outside of the div.

Its acting correctly as children can exist & be hoverable outside of the block area of an element.

This technique is used frequently to move inner pieces of block elements by using negative-margin/padding/absolute positioning etc. yet those pieces will always maintain the hover-ability of the parent.

Comment: I mentioned in my question that using overflow: hidden solves the problem.  I am more interested in why the content maintains hover-ability when outside of its bounding box.

Comment: Apparently, every child of the div gets the div's hoverability, even if they're outside of the div's boundaries. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RVgzV/8/), where the span is far outside the div, but still contributes to the div's properties. As I said, I was surprised too! But this explains it.

Comment: I would upvote this comment if I had enough rep, but I unfortunately do not.  I am still wondering if this is an implementation detail common to all browsers, or a part of the specification.  I will update the question to reflect this.  Also, if you rewrite your comment as an answer, and no one can adequately explain what part of the css spec specifies this behavior, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The div is not incorrectly sized. It is the normal behavior.
You have used CSS incorrectly. The div-height is defined by the number of lines in it. You have given a bigger font-size than line-height, that means it can be only taken the max-line-height to define the number of needed lines.

By the way, what sense makes it to define the font-seize larger than the line-height?

Comment: Obviously, I am using CSS incorrectly, or I would be getting a different result.  My question is more: in what way am I using CSS incorrectly?  The spec specifically says that font sizes can be larger than line heights.

Comment: Then the guy that has written the specs has not thought about it. That is the same like trying to pack a bar-chair in a shoe-box

Comment: In this particular case, I would like to make my dashes larger than they otherwise would be, without expanding the size of the containing box.  But the why isn't really important; I'm sure there are lots of cases where you might want something like this.  The question is why, if I am following the CSS specification, does the behavior happen, and where does it specify that.

Comment: It's not a problem to enlarge the font-size of some particular parts, But then you need at least the same line-height, or set the line-height to auto (default)